# Is there a way of controlling the position and colour of a stop on a color ramp node?

Tags: node-editor

Conceptually I want what's in the picture. Rather than having the position / colour of the stop only being set in the node UI, can I plug another node in to control it?

[image]

Comment: Alas, no.  The idea is discussed in the developer's lists from time to time, but nobody has ever come up with an acceptable proposal for how to do it.

Comment: instead of using colorramp you could use maprange node. This you can control by other nodes.

Comment: @MartyFouts is that because there's no way of having a variable number of inputs in a node?

Comment: @stib Yes.  There's no way to do that.  The alternative would be to have a single input that works like a vector, like color values, but that can be variable length.  But there's no way to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but this might be useful for someone. You can use input values and drivers to control color ramp node settings.

1. Add an input->value node
2. Right click on the number and choose `copy as new driver`
3. Right click on the color ramp Pos and choose `paste driver`

You can do this for RGBA values but not HSV or HSL and the input value can come from wherever you want (almost) but certainly object custom properties.

If you want to do more than just patch a value in you can right click on the driven property and choose `edit driver` then change the type to `scripted expression` and add a formula in the expression. That way you can have one slider to alter all the stops on the color ramp.

However what you **can't** do is use the output of another node. To do that you have to set up something with maprange nodes

[image]